# Drop Down Menu won't show up, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script

This is my code below, the drop down menu wont' show up! I saw in another post here that could be because the script wasn't attached to any sheet so I went ahead and added the getdocument but still not working.
I have set a trigger on event from spreadsheet On open for this onpen function.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks

```
function onOpen(){
  doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var menudrop = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  menudrop.createMenu('Refresh Reports');
  menudrop.createMenu.addItem('Refresh CO', 'copyClearPasteAUDashboard','combinedLive');
  menudrop.createAddonMenu.addItem('Refresh SW', 'copyClearPasteSWDashboard','combinedLive')
  menudrop.addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `var menudrop = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();` should be this  `var menudrop = DocumentApp.getUi();`